# format type number with comma on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, format

I want to format all input type numbers into comma separated value, I found the code for conversion over the net but it is not working in the fashion I want, it should convert all the input number into a specific format.

I also tried, doing type text but it still wont work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".number").each(function() {
    var _val = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(_val.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="locationError" class="number" type="text" value="1221312321" readonly/>
<input name="locationError" type="text" value="1221312321"  class="number" readonly/>
```

This is different since i want it on document on load

Comment: change to type=text

Comment: i tried but it wot work

Comment: works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/tvkswd75/

Comment: you probably didnt change the jquery selector. see my answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `type="number"` to `type="text"` or type="currency"  inside your html.

Also remember, to change the jquery selector to `$("input[type='text']")` or `$("input[type='currency']")` for working in your particular snippet scenario!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='text']").each(function() {
    var x = $(this).val();
    alert(x);
    $(this).val(x.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="locationError" type="text" value="1221312321" />
<input name="locationError" type="text" value="1221312321" />
```

Comment: maybe i did not include the jquery when testing the code in jsfindle.. but thanks

Comment: added a class number instead of text to have unique

Comment: Much better. I just was replicating from your snippet and editting the least, for a minimal changed answer.

Comment: Did you know you could use [`.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) to add commas instead of using regex? `var val = parseFloat(this.value).toLocaleString();`